# How to show a field seperately in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have `Reviews & Ratings` serializer. I want to show the total count of reviews in response. The current implementation I am getting review count but it shows on all review response like below:

```
[
    {
        "review_count": 2,
        "user": "don sebastian",
        "rating": 3.9,
        "review": "Rating for pendant 1 by Don",
        "created_at": "2022-11-27",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-27"
    },
    {
        "review_count": 2,
        "user": "Jackson Patrick Gomez",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "review": "cool review Pendant 1",
        "created_at": "2022-11-27",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-29"
    }
]
```

What I want to get is like this `review_count` seperatley

```
[
   "review_count": 2,
    {
        "user": "don sebastian",
        "rating": 3.9,
        "review": "Rating for pendant 1 by Don",
        "created_at": "2022-11-27",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-27"
    },
    {
        "user": "Jackson Patrick Gomez",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "review": "cool review Pendant 1",
        "created_at": "2022-11-27",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-29"
    }
]
```

#Serializer.py

```
class ReviewSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = SerializerMethodField()
    review_count = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ReviewRatings
        fields = ["review_count", "user", "rating", "review", "created_at", "updated_at"]

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.user.first_name} {obj.user.last_name}"
    
    def get_review_count(self, obj):
```

#Views.py

```
class ShowReviews(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_slug = self.kwargs['product_slug']
        rating = request.GET.get('rating')
        reviews = ReviewRatings.objects.filter(product__slug=product_slug)
        review_count = reviews.count()
        if rating == 'lowest':
            reviews = reviews.order_by('rating')
        elif rating == 'highest':
            reviews = reviews.order_by('-rating')
        if not reviews:
            return Response({"error": "No reviews for this product yet"}, status=404)
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True, context={"count":review_count})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

#Edited Views.py

```
class ShowReviews(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_slug = self.kwargs['product_slug']
        rating = request.GET.get('rating')
        reviews = ReviewRatings.objects.filter(product__slug=product_slug)
        review_count = reviews.count()
        if rating == 'lowest':
            reviews = reviews.order_by('rating')
        elif rating == 'highest':
            reviews = reviews.order_by('-rating')
        if not reviews:
            return Response({"error": "No reviews for this product yet"}, status=404)
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
        dict_copy = serializer.data.copy()
        dict_copy[0]={"review_count": review_count}
        return Response(dict_copy, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Can you add your endpoint functions? views etc

Comment: I have updated the question and added views. Please check it

Comment: Im not seeing anything that changed besides your `review_count` addition. Maybe you made a change in your db?

Comment: No changes in db. I followed  your second approach directly editing the response and its working. I'm getting all reviews. But Why did you said "it will do no good because its outside serializer". Isn't appropriate to write like that?

Comment: I was referring based on accessibility since you are directly declaring it outside of your serializer. nothing to do with the value changing

Comment: So writing like that is not a bad idea right?

Comment: I'd assume it wouldn't be optimal without being completely sure, but as long as it works for your purpose it would suffice.

Comment: Thanks man.
But I have no idea why the first approach doesn't show all the reviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I would assume is to edit your endpoint response directly.

Assuming you approached `DRF` as instructed; ([this](https://blog.logrocket.com/django-rest-framework-create-api/) is an easy guideline for you to set up), you are going to remove `review_count` from your serializer and approach your get method like so:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      ..........
      serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
      dict_copy = serializer.data.copy()
      dict_copy[0]=str(Review.objects.all().count()) # or wherever that count comes from
      return Response(dict_copy, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This way you are making a copy of the serializer and then appending your value there. Since `serializer.data` returns an array with a dict inside in order to access that point then you will do `dict_copy[0]`. Otherwise if you want to have access to it as a `key`-`value` pair you can assign it as

```
      dict_copy[0]={"review_count": str(Review.objects.all().count())}
```

and your result will be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "review_count": "4"
    },
    {
        "user": "don sebastian",
        "rating": 3.9,
        "review": "Rating for pendant 1 by Don",
        "created_at": "2022-11-27",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-27"
    },
```

Lastly you can try directly editing your response and adding there a key-pair value but I assume it will do you no good as this is outside of your serializer:

```
  x = Review.objects.all().count()
  return Response(( {"review_count":str(x)}, serializer.data), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
[
    {
        "review_count": "4"
    },
    [
    {
       
        "user": "don sebastian",
        "rating": 3.9,
        "review": "Rating for pendant 1 by Don",
        "created_at": "2022-11-27",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-27"
    },
        ....
]
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code?

Comment: Yes. You are making a copy of your existing serializer data and appending your value there

Comment: Check my answer again and let me know

Comment: Yes i got the review count separately but There is a problem, I am only get one review only. I have two reviews for a product but now it only shows one review

Comment: look again maybe you changed something in your original queryset. This change should not affect your `queryset` results

Comment: I have also added the views like you guided, can you please check it